# Raspberry not working though ssh and cannot mount with usb

Tags: mount

Yesterday my raspberrypi was working fine, instead of shutting down properly just pulled the power plug. now when i turn on my raspberrypi it i see the red led on. but cannot ssh, i also have apache installed to i cannot see the localhost page as well.

So i tried to mount it but is see only one "overlay" folder and bunch of files, i need to access my home folder.

i only see this
[image: raspberry pi sdcard]

can i access my raspberry pi /home, /media, etc folder from sdcard when i plug it in with usb

Comment: There are two partitions, most of the stuff is on the second one.  If you are using MS Windows most likely it cannot even see the second one.

Answer (score 1):

From your post it appears you are using a linux distro, but you are looking at the wrong partition. Type "df" to show mounted file systems. You should have an entry for mmcblk0p1. You can also get information typing "mount". Can you post the results of these commands? Eventually we want to get the mmcblk0p2 mounted so we can run fsck on it to attempt to repair it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file system is still in tact then you should be able to plug it into a linux system and read the files.

Comment: Yes Thats the thing as you can see in the image that is all what i can see

Comment: The folder and files you are listing are the normal files found in the boot partition (/dev/mmcblk0p1 formated as a vfat partition.) This partition only accounts for about 50-60 MB of the sd card. The rest of the operating system, program files and data are on a linux ext4 partition (/dev/mmcblk0p2) which you won't be able to see on a windows computer. That is why you would need a linux host to mount the ext4 partition to see its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your home partition, Just plug your SD Card and see the mounted drives (The one which have large space is your storage partition for this you can do df -h and see the mounted drives)

And you can also ssh, as in your image that you posted have cmdline.txt
just open it and write ip=192.168.1.23 (Or any ip "PS: better to check your netmask") at last of file  which will give static ip to your Pi and to which you can connect easily then try to boot it and try to ssh. it will ssh.